# How to upgrade to ubuntu 18.04 version from 16.04 using terminal

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade, updates, update-manager

I want to upgrade to ubuntu version 18.04 from 16.04.I have taken the backup.

My question is whether update manager will give options to select which version 18.04 or 20.04
as both are available and i don't want to upgrade to 20.04.

Upon some searching in askubuntu i found below steps to be followed to upgrade.

Step1:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt install update-manager-core

Step2:
sudo vi /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades

Step3:
sudo do-release-upgrade

Can anyone please let me know if i am following correct steps.Is there any other steps i need to  follow to do upgrade to 18.04

Comment: The `update-manager-core` package should have already been installed on your Ubuntu system. If you removed it in the past, then it seems likely that you made other changes that might doom a release-upgrade. You should not need to use `dist-upgrade` at all (you should be using `full-upgrade` anyway on Ubuntu). You should not need to edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` unless you are undoing some previous setting change. `sudo` is optional with do-release-upgrade -- if omitted, the upgrader will ask for your password.

Comment: “i don't want to upgrade to 20.04” Your system won’t be upgraded from 16.04 to 20.04 in one step. The upgrade of Ubuntu goes every time to the _next_ release of the same type (regular, LTS). To upgrade from 16.04 to 20.04, you would have to do the upgrade process twice (16.04 → 18.04 → 20.04).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Update Manager or the shell.

Both will offer to update you only to the next LTS of Ubuntu. They won't offer to skip releases.

To prepare for a release-upgrade:

1. Return your system to as close to stock condition as possible.

   If you have added PPAs or non-Ubuntu sources, remove them and uninstall the packages that came from those sources.
2. Upgrade your system on the old release: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.

   If you have held broken packages, packages not upgraded, or ANY error message, then stop. Seek help in AskUbuntu before proceeding. Release-upgrading a broken system rarely fixes the problem, and often makes things worse.
3. **(Optional)** Backup your data and prepare an Ubuntu install USB stick.

   This step provides insurance from unexpected problems. If you are inexperienced in data recovery, have limited recovery resources on hand, or have a history of package/upgrade problems, then definitely take a few minutes to do this step!
4. Launch the upgrade process using Update Manager or `do-release-upgrade`